# How to encode xml produce in UCS-2 (SQL Server) to utf-8

Tags: sql-server, xml, utf-8, ssis, encode

I have ssis package to produce a xml file(which is in USC-2) for 3rd party company. When file is loaded to their system, it is failed and I was told that they need to use Notepad++ to convert it to utf-8 in order to load it successfully. I have added  to the top of the file but no joy. Can someone explain how to produce xml in ssis/sql server in utf-8?

I have compared original file in UCS-2 with converted file in UTF-8 but only difference I can see following line has been removed in converted file.

```
<value visId0="61524" visId1="X240863" visId2="0" visId3="3154" visId4="6" calendarYearVisId="2017" valueTypeVisId="AB" currencyVisId="GBP" value="121400"/>
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Perhaps this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12512687/sql-server-utf8-howto

Comment: Thanks @Shnugo. Extra step has been added to convert to utf-8 in ssis as found in [link](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic719421-149-1.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32980009/tsql-for-xml-exporting-actual-utf-8-encoded-data) which says

...The workaround is simple albeit counterintuitive - add a Data Conversion Transformation step between the OLE DB Source and the Flat-File Destination that converts your input "Dat" column from DT_NTEXT to DT_TEXT with a codepage of 65001. Then you feed the newly transformed column directly to the output column in your flat-file dest. ...

But it referred to [this](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic719421-149-1.aspx)